# Mule maven dependency errors - REST calls using com.sun.jersey

Tags: java, apache, maven, mule, jersey-client

I'm running 2 mule flows with custom built connectors using jersey-client for REST calls:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

- Java version: 1.8.0_144
- Mule-version: 3.7.0 CE
- Apache Maven 3.5.3

When building the mule-flows with `mvn clean package`, the following libs are added:

```
[INFO] Adding <com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.2> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.mule.modules:tickster-connector:jar:1.0.0> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <se.twoegroup:two-egroup-connector:jar:2.1.0> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.3> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.19.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <org.mule.modules:mosaic-connector:jar:1.0.2> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1> as a lib
[INFO] Adding <javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1> as a lib
```

Each flow runs perfectly while running by itself, but when the 2 flows are deployed together in the same mule-instance I get the exception stack trace below:

```
2018-07-11 11:33:00.098 ERROR com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory - The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
  at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:210) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:180) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:283) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:163) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:171) ~[?:?]
  at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:683) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.modules.tickster.rest.TicksterClient.<init>(TicksterClient.java:30) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.modules.tickster.config.ConnectorConfig.connect(ConnectorConfig.java:39) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.modules.tickster.generated.connectivity.ConnectorConfigTicksterConnectorAdapter.connect(ConnectorConfigTicksterConnectorAdapter.java:34) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.modules.tickster.generated.connectivity.ConnectorConfigTicksterConnectorAdapter.connect(ConnectorConfigTicksterConnectorAdapter.java:10) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.devkit.3.9.0.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.makeObject(ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.java:47) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.devkit.3.9.0.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.makeObject(ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.java:19) ~[?:?]
  at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220) ~[commons-pool-1.6.jar:1.6]
  at org.mule.modules.tickster.generated.connectivity.TicksterConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.acquireConnection(TicksterConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:234) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.modules.tickster.generated.connectivity.TicksterConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.acquireConnection(TicksterConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:44) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.devkit.3.9.0.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.java:48) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.devkit.3.9.0.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.java:23) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.security.oauth.process.RetryProcessInterceptor.execute(RetryProcessInterceptor.java:84) ~[mule-module-devkit-support-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.devkit.3.9.0.internal.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessTemplate.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessTemplate.java:36) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.modules.tickster.generated.processors.GetBookingsMessageProcessor.doProcess(GetBookingsMessageProcessor.java:119) ~[?:?]
  at org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.process(DevkitBasedMessageProcessor.java:88) ~[mule-module-devkit-support-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:98) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:231) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.SimpleMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(SimpleMessageProcessorChain.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:76) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeEvent(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:511) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver$1.process(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:168) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver$1.process(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:148) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.pollWith(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:147) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.poll(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:216) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.mule.modules.schedulers.cron.CronJob.execute(CronJob.java:33) ~[mule-module-schedulers-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
  at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:?]
  at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:?]
  2018-07-11 11:33:00.197 ERROR com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors - The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable) at parameter index 1
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader(com.sun.jersey.spi.MessageBodyWorkers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable) at parameter index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter(com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable,com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable) at parameter index 1
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: com.sun.jersey.spi.MessageBodyWorkers com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider.bodyWorker
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.setFeaturesAndProperties(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.setConfiguration(com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties) at parameter at index 0 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2]
```